# How to interpret the Throughput metric for Semantic Segmentation?

Tags: metrics, evaluation, amazon-sagemaker, semantic-segmentation

I am beginning to train a semantic segmentation model in AWS Sagermaker and they provide the following metrics for the output. I understand mIOU, loss, and pixel accuracy, but I do not know what throughput is or how to interpret it. Please see the image below and let me know if you need additional information.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throughput is reported in records per second (i.e. images per second). It shows how fast the algorithm can iterate over training or validation data. For example, with a throughput of 30 records/sec it would take a minute to iterate over 1800 images.